# Mock location on android 4.2.2 (Nexus 4)

Tags: android, gps, mocking

I am looking for the "mock locations" option on android 4.2.2 (Nexus 4) but I was unable to find it. Usually it can be found at "Preferences => Applications => Devlopment / Mock Locations"

I searched on the google help center, and i was "googling" but nothing...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Allow mock locations` is located in "`Settings` > `Developer Options`".
To enable "`Developer Options`" repeatedly touch "`About` > `Build Number`".
Good luck!